# How to format html based on query value that is a string

Tags: html, css, asp.net, sql-server-2008, razor

Using ASP.NET razor and SQL Server 2008 R2

I have a local variable that is declared thus:

```
var tsmMtd = db.QueryValue("  
  SELECT  b.Name, SUM(subtotal) totalSUM  
  FROM DR_TRANS a  
  INNER JOIN Staff b ON a.Salesno = b.Staffno  
  WHERE a.salesno in (12,23,28,30)  
    AND a.TRANSDATE >= dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, getdate()), 0)   
    AND a.REF3 = 'Invoice'  
  GROUP BY b.Name  
  ORDER BY totalSUM DESC  
");
```

Now that returns an array of names from the table, sorted by sales value. calling it in the HTML later as

```
@tsmMtd.ToString()
```

which prints the topmost name. OK, all good. NOW....

I need to format the text of the page based on that top salesperson. I want their name to go blue if they *are* the top salesperson.This is what I did on the 'actual sales' figure for a salesperson:

```
<span class=@(salesval12  > 6000 ? "blue" : "red")>@salesval12.ToString("C")</span>
```

This works fine to change the colour of the text if it is over the 6000 value. (classes red and blue are defined higher up the page). So, I did this:

```
<span class=@(tsmMtd = "CHARLIE JONES" ? "blue" : "red")>Charlie</span>
```

but it fails at loading saying **Compiler Error Message:** CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

OK, so what I need to know is

1. what I am doing wrong
2. what I should be doing

Any and all help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
@(tsmMtd = "CHARLIE JONES" ? "blue" : "red")
```

It should be

```
@(tsmMtd == "CHARLIE JONES" ? "blue" : "red")
```

You wrote one equal sign instead of two. With one it just save `CHARLIE JONES` to `tsmMtd` variable and then try to compare that string variable as condition and compiler display an error about it